# Are there any common reasons a file in iOS /Documents directory might disappear between launches

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, nsdocument, nsdocumentdirectory

I have an app that is storing several files in the Documents directory, that have a good reason persist between launches. I am storing the name of one of them in NSUserDefaults as **@"currentGameVideo"** and I check to make sure that file still exists when I launch, before I do anything with it.

However it did get me thinking just of a theoretical question: **Are** there any legitimate reasons that perhaps someone would use my app, it would save the actual video files, and also store the name in NSUserDefaults, but then they quit the app, come back later, and for some reason, the NSUserDefaults entry is still there, but the video files are not?

Related: Would there be any conceivable reason that SOME video files might disappear and others would remain?

Comment: Short answer, that's not the optimal outcome. 1) how are you saving said files? 2) How are you ensuring they are valid before proceeding?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html

Comment: See the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452098/nsdocumentdirectory-files-disappear-in-ios