# NSDocumentDirectory files disappear in ios

Tags: ios, file, ios8, nsdocumentdirectory

I want to save a mp4 video in my folder but when I open again the app, this file is nil. But when I save the file, I can open it, so it seems that it disappears from the folder.

Save:

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:exportUrl];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",videoName];

self.path_video_to_save = tempPath;

BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:YES];

if (success) 
    NSLog(@"saved");
else
    NSLog(@"not saved!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
```

I get the success in true so it's ok and I can play my video well.

```
NSString *path_video = [dict objectForKey:@"path"]; //dictionary where I save the path, the same before and after closing app

NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path_video]];

if (videoData == nil){
    NSLog(@"DATA NULL");
}
else
    NSLog(@"DATA OK");

    NSLog(@"PATH:%@", path_video);

    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path_video]];
```

and at this point it work fine.

But when I close and open again the app and I get the path, my app crash and I have the log "`DATA NULL`" I don't understand why when I close my app the file disappear... what's up?

thanks

Comment: Are you using device or simulator ? Ofc I suggest to try it on a real device.

Comment: I use a real device... iPhone 5s

Comment: Ok I just tried it on an iPad and it works fine, what happens in my iPhone?

Comment: I guess it is another So question ;) (Joke) 
Does your iPhone have sufficient disc space?

I would suggest to try and write data NOT automatically (it will write directly to you path and not to the RAM first just to make a TEST check)

Comment: I have enough space in my device, I'll try that you suggest me.

Comment: I just tried, the same problem!!!

Comment: Just because you receive `YES` doesn't mean it works well. Pass an NSError pointer in the call and try to `NSLog` the localizedDescription of the NSError if it's not `nil`.

Comment: -- meaning - use the `writeToFile options: error:`.

Comment: Done!! error is null!!!

Comment: Do you have another iPhone to check ?

Comment: In that case, use the same thing for reading - `dataWithContentsOfURL: options: error:` and check the error.

Comment: No such file or directory, this is the error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because in iOS 8 +  the name of the Application folder is renamed each time you launch it.

Check it in /Users/"your username"/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/"device name"/data/Containers/Data/Application/"application name" (Test in simulator).

So, you have to save the path without the document directory. And when you are trying to retrieve the path you have to add the document directory before the path you saved previously.

Like let your custom folder name is "Save_Video" and file name is "video_01.mp4".
Your file saving path will be "Application document directory"/Save_Video/video_01.mp4

Then you have to store only "Save_Video/video_01.mp4"(in Database/ NSUserDefaults) and when you are retrieving the file the path should be

"Application document directory"/Save_Video/video_01.mp4